# Invisible files taking up storage on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

As you can see from the screenshot, there are no files on My Drive.

[image: My Drive]

But the quota of My Drive is 4.7 GB used.

When I click Settings->View items taking up storage, the webpage returns empty result which takes up the 4.7 GB storage.

Reproduce: upload some files to My Drive, then move them to one of Team Drives. But I cannot reproduce every time.

This status has lasted for several hours. Maybe not the backend cache problem?

I've also rechecked the differences between files moved from My Drive and files uploaded directly to Team Drive. Nothing useful information.

Why there are invisible files taking up storage of My Drive?

--

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Google's [help page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6374270?hl=en) explains that there are a number of locations other than Gdrive which contribute. Have you checked those?

Comment: @Kapil Thanks. I just checked Settings->Manage Apps, but there's no hidden data. I've also updated the screenshots to my post.

Comment: And emptied the trash?

Comment: @Appleoddity Thank you. The files in Trash takes up the storage. Maybe I have to downvote my question...

Comment: Remember that Gmail and Google Photos (full resolution photos) also count toward this limit.